# GN - Delay animation per instance

Tags: geometry-nodes

I recreated [Bradley's node tree](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24QPV2Y0QeA) of flipping book pages.

[image]

He is using several his own node-groups. One of them is *Delay Fall-Off* where I can delay start, but since I generate instances of final book it is applied to all instances of course.

[image]

- How can I set delay per instance
- How can I control delay by another object (Empty) or even better by value of procedural texture in place of instance.

Here is whole node tree ...
[image]

[image]

I didn't fully understand the whole node-tree, I will need more time ... (or entire of my life :)

Comment: Without putting in a lot of research. You can simply subtract some scaled value of the index of each instance from the value thats animating them. So find the value thats animating the books. Add a math subtract node there. Create an index node. Multiply that index value by some scale. Then connect that to the subtract node.

Comment: If you mean [this setup](https://imgur.com/I6Zgdq0) ... it still affects all instances.

Comment: Hi! I found it almost impossible to reverse-engineer Bradley's groups.. but I did rough out [one of my own](https://imgur.com/a/fNWisnv). It would take a bit of tidying up to make it half-useful to anyone else, though. Is that of any interest?

Comment: @RobinBetts Sure, awesome result :) Cover control is welcomed (in the best it should be UV textured as well). Final goal is like table full of books animated as coming "wind" opening books from right to left on the table with a bit of randomness. Anim ends with open books on random page. Sure also random book thickness is welcomed too, but since it would be taken almost from top view current version can fake illusion too. GN are hard for me, so any step further is welcomed. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm afraid there is currently no workable solution in this specific case with instantiation: An instantiation occurs at different points, but always exactly one (!) object is instantiated. One single object which is copied to n points and can no longer be changed after instantiation.

Comment: @quellenform Hm ... but if you check the RobinBett's link, there seems to be a way.

Comment: ...possibly he is right. But maybe he just copies the objects with different properties to different positions instead of instantiating them. ... @RobinBetts, please tell us more.

Comment: @quellenform etc. sorry for delay, busy, and it's a bit of a tangle. vklidu's extra requirements actually change it quite a lot, chiefly, to thicken the books and cover the spine? Here's the [messy version](https://pasteall.org/blend/13b33eb7825443e9918c1e1ee3a2ac30) without any concessions to being understood :(. Got to figure out how to make it a reasonable BSE answer.

Comment: @RobinBetts, thanks for sharing! You are right: if you do the page flip after realizing the instances, it is possible this way.

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks for blend ... easier for me to study :) For the project I had to speed it up by old school way ... Render one book and composite in VSE in a few minutes :)

Comment: @vklidu I'm really sorry for the delay.. I got all tangled up, trying to make a kind of modular version so the books could have spines and thickness, pages on arcs, etc.. I still don't know how I would squeeze that down into a one-subject BSE answer. _I've_ learned a lot, but that's not much help to you.